# Entity extraction on large documents

Tags: ibm-watson, azure-cognitive-services

I have a need to extract entities from word and pdf documents. Documents can be in the range of 10 to 20 pages. Are there scalable library/APIs available that we can plug into our processing pipeline? Any comparative study of different solutions will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Watson Natural Language Understanding](https://console.bluemix.net/catalog/services/natural-language-understanding) (you'll need to get an IBM ID and then login to see this content - don't worry , cost is $0).  With [Watson Natural Language Understanding](https://console.bluemix.net/catalog/services/natural-language-understanding) you will want to look at the [API Explorer](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/natural-language-understanding/api/v1/) to find the correct API syntax to use to get the results that you are looking for.

I also noticed that mention Word/PDF documents.  You will need to convert those using the [Watson Discovery](https://console.bluemix.net/catalog/services/discovery) service, and then you can pass the converted documents to [Watson Natural Language Understanding](https://console.bluemix.net/catalog/services/natural-language-understanding), which takes in JSON, text or HTML inputs.